# ui is protected, but how to use it in the reimplemented Qthread run() function

Tags: qt, user-interface, qthread

I want to reemplement the run function creating my own class of QThread.

I've created this,

```
class MyThread : public QThread
{
public:
    void run();
};

void MyThread::run()
{
    gui w;
    w.listen_device(w.ui->comboBox->currentIndex());
    exec();
}
```

I can't use QPaint outside the main thread so I'm giving the value as an argument to my listen_device function.

I know ui from gui is protected, so how can I get this value?

Thanks.

Comment: It's more than just paint that can't be in a background thread. QWidgets cannot be created in a background thread at all. If your widgets are being created in `gui`'s constructor, you'll need to rethink your design. Keep only logic in the background thread and emit signals. In the main thread, you can catch those signals and update the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create public method in `gui` class which will return `ui->comboBox->currentIndex();`

```
public:
  int gui::getCurrentIndex() // or whatever
  { 
    return ui->comboBox->currentIndex();
  }
```

And don't subclass `QThread`, use `moveToThread()` on `QObject` instead.